# Facebook javascript api

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, replace

I need help in this code:

```
FB.api("/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday,picture, link", dojo.hitch(this, function(response) {
var birthdays = response.data; //list of friend objects from facebook
var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
var upcoming = [];
dojo.forEach(birthdays, function(item) {
    if (item.birthday) {
        var bday = item.birthday;
        //if the birthday is after today
        if (currentMonth <= bday.substr(0, 2) * 1 && new Date().getDate() <= new Date(bday).getDate()) {
            upcoming.push(item);
        }
    }
});

//set the year to current year because of birth years being different.
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
upcoming = upcoming.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.birthday).setYear(year) - new Date(b.birthday).setYear(year);
});

console.log(upcoming);//console log here, but do whatever you want with the sorted friends
```

}));

The app is about wishing upcoming people birthdays. This code is actually in the script tags in my index.html file. Included in the script tags is the fb.login etc that are needed to log into the Facebook. I'm confused in the above code. How could I call the above code so that individually a single persons name return. Then call his picture so it returns. Then the link etc so that the person could use it to wish his friend through this app on Facebook. This is because I want to use the upcoming persons birthday, link etc separately.

Comment: I want to use the id,name,birthday,picture, link of an upcoming person's birthday separately in the above code in HTML. Could please tell me the way it's done?

Comment: You question not really clear. What does it mean "separately"? You already have all fields in forEach loop.  That's stopping you to use fields separately or together?

Comment: Well thank you for the reply. I mean that lets say i get your birthday as 17 December which is upcoming. I would get it though the above code./            But now lets say another friend has a birthday on the 17th.First i want your name and i would add it to a division in html where it would stand in the box next to your picture.Then ofcource I would add the picture and the link through which i would post something on the your wall. But how do i get this done? Because there are several elements in the upcoming box and i have to use on at a time.

Comment: I have to get your each of your name , birthday etc one at a time and then the other persons. Now how do I get this done and execute it in my index.html, one at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

together

```
var parentEl = document.getElementById('id_of_your_html_element_where_you_want_show_users');

upcoming.forEach(function(user){
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = user.name;
    parentEl.appendChild(el);
});
```

or separate

```
var parentEl = document.getElementById('id_of_your_html_element_where_you_want_show_users');
var user = upcoming[some_index];
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = user.name;
parentEl.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: Thank you so much igor benikov.Is it linking to the above code? If so could you please explain?

Comment: yes, linked. Your upcoming array contain objects with all fields: id,name,birthday,picture, link. Try to use your code. Couse you need html-element with id as in example

Comment: I attach this to the current code and then call the fb.api and would it work?

Comment: i hope )). I can't see your full html-code.